# How to make this object collide with a bottom of the screen? (Pygame)

Tags: pygame, collision-detection

How do I make this object collide with the bottom of the screen?

```
def update(self):
    """Atualiza a posição do foguete de acordo com a flag"""
    # Atualiza o valor  centro da espaçonave, e não o retângolo

    if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
        self.centerx += self.ai_settings.foguete_speed_factor

    if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
        self.centerx -= self.ai_settings.foguete_speed_factor

    if self.moving_top and self.rect.top > 0:
        self.centery -= self.ai_settings.foguete_speed_factor

    if self.moving_bottom:
        self.centery += self.ai_settings.foguete_speed_factor
```

[image: enter image description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to keep moving down while the rocket hasn't hit the bottom of the screen, then:

```
if self.moving_bottom and self.rect.bottom < self.screen_rect.bottom:
    self.centery += self.ai_settings.foguete_speed_factor
```

Comment: It also looks like it should be `self.rect.centery` not `self.centery`, but we can't say this definitely unless we see a complete example @MikaelAndrade. And to set the bottom of the rocket exactly to the bottom of the screen add: `self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom`.